# Why can't I define nat in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I was following the [tutorial for Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2017/doc/prog-prove.pdf), and typed in the following example from section 2.2.2:

```
theory FailedBasicAdditionProof
  imports Main
begin

datatype nat = 0 | Suc nat

fun add :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"add 0 n = n" |
"add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"

lemma add_02: "add m 0 = m"
apply(induction m)
apply(auto)
  done
end
```

but got the error

```
Legacy feature! Bad name binding: "nat.0"⌂ 
Legacy feature! Bad name binding: "nat.0"⌂ 
Bad name: "nat.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to look at [the datatype docs](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2017/doc/datatypes.pdf), the exact same example is done, except with the word `Zero` instead of the number `0`.

If you replace `0` with `Zero`, the example should work. I think this is a naming convention that was probably changed or added later.

The correct example is here:

```
theory CorrectBasicAdditionProof
  imports Main
begin

datatype nat = Zero | Suc nat

fun add :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"add Zero n = n" |
"add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"

lemma add_02: "add m Zero = m"
apply(induction m)
apply(auto)
  done
end
```